# I get this error Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-sdk

I get this error when emulating my application

```
[ERROR] [GRADLE] 
[ERROR] [GRADLE] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ERROR] [GRADLE] 
[ERROR] [GRADLE] * What went wrong:
[ERROR] [GRADLE] Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
[ERROR] [GRADLE] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
[ERROR] [GRADLE]    > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount found in modules jetified-google-play-services-tigoosh (google-play-services-tigoosh.jar) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
[ERROR] [GRADLE]      Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker found in modules jetified-google-play-services-tigoosh (google-play-services-tigoosh.jar) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
```

Titanium version 11.1.1

Answer (score 0):

ti.goosh hasn't been updated in years. There is an alternative at https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-cloud-messaging that works up to the latest SDK version. That also includes the latest Android version and the permissions you'll need to get in order to use push. Ti.Goosh doesn't have those permissions. So I highly recommend switching the module. The documentation has a complete example and there is another full tutorial at https://fromzerotoapp.com/ah-push-it-use-firebase-push-in-your-app/ with all the steps.

There is one PR in the ti.goosh repo https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh/pull/123 in case you still want to use that module. But you would need to update everything inside the module and make it compatible with Android 13